# receive error message can't convert symbol into integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have the following code in my controller of my twilio application, and as you will see an error in the "id = user..." line:

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
def play
    user = Refugee.find_all_by_cell_number(params[:id]) && Student.find_all_by_cell_number(params[:id])
    id = user[:last_class].to_i
    lesson = RecordedLesson.find(id).next
    user[:last_class] = lesson.id
    user.save
    @audio_lesson_url = lesson.sound_file.url
    render :action => "play.xml.builder", :layout => false
end
end
```

Then I get the following error message

```
    app/controllers/calls_controller.rb:7:in `play'=2012-09-18T04:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):
```

This is in spite of the fact that I ran the following migration

```
    class ChangeLastClassOfStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        change_column :students, :last_class, :integer, :null => true

      end
    end
```

Comment: ok, thanks, sorry, I am not a frequent stackoverflow user, so didn't really know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your user object is valid and responds to last_class method. have you tried just doing this?

```
id = user.last_class
```

Since your last_class is already an attribute and an integer there is no reason to convert it.

Comment: problem is for case where user.last_class = nil; which it does when a new user (really a Student) object is created.